# ¿Cómo utilizar GROUPBY en Python para hacer un promedio por fecha que incluya todos los elementos?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo el siguiente DataFrame en Python, en principio con 2 valores distintos para la columna "título":

```
titulo  fecha      rendim_acumulado
Peras   2019-05-03  1.000000
Uvas    2019-05-03  1.031752
Uvas    2019-05-06  1.031752
Peras   2019-05-06  1.000000
Uvas    2019-05-07  1.031752
Uvas    2019-05-08  1.031752
Peras   2019-05-08  1.000000
Uvas    2019-05-09  1.031752
Peras   2019-05-09  1.000000
```

Quiero obtener el promedio del rendimiento_acumulado por fecha.
El problema es que algunas fechas tienen algún título faltante (como sucede el día 2019-05-07). En esos casos yo quisiera que para calcular el promedio utilice el rendimiento_acumulado de ese título en la fecha anterior. Es decir que por ejemplo el día 2019-05-07 haga el promedio entre 1.031752 y 1.000000 (dado que 1.000000 es el último valor del título Peras).

El siguiente código no me sirve, porque me ignora el título cuya fecha no está en el Dataframe:

```
df.groupby("fecha") ['rendim_acumulado'].mean()
```

Comment: no veo eso donde dices titulo faltante, podrias aclararlo porfavor, se agradece

Comment: Si te fijas en el DataFrame, para cada fecha existe el rendimiento acumulado tanto de Peras como de Uvas, pero por ejemplo para la fecha 2019-05-07 sólo está registrado el rendimiento acumulado de Uvas, y falta el de Peras. Es ahí cuando el promedio me arroja valores distintos a los que busco obtener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

espero que esto te sirva:

Lo primero que hice fue evaluar por titulo la completitud, unirlo en un dataframe final y con base en este ya hacer el groupby.

```
titulos=[x for x in df.titulo.unique()]

new_df=pd.DataFrame()
for titulo in titulos:
    #fist part to complete Dataframe data
    df_copy=df.loc[df['titulo']==titulo]
    
    #this part fill incomplete data between dates
    idx = pd.date_range(df.fecha.values[0], df.fecha.values[-1])
    df_copy.set_index('fecha',inplace=True,drop=True)
    df_copy= df_copy.reindex(idx, fill_value=np.nan)
    df_copy.fillna(method='ffill',inplace=True)
    new_df=new_df.append(df_copy,ignore_index=False)
    
#Ordering the final DataFrame - optional
new_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
new_df = new_df.rename(columns={'index': 'fecha'})
new_df.sort_values(by=['fecha'])

#groupby with the complete DataFrame
new_df.groupby("fecha") ['rendim_acumulado'].mean()
```